# React Js : Handle Nested Element In State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have below Code :-

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
const iState ={
    Name : '',
    Email :'',
    Salary :0,
    Error:{
        EName:'*',
        EEmail:'*',
        ESalary:'*'
    }

}
function ReactForm() {
    
const [state, setstate] = useState(iState);
    function validationHandler(e)
    {
        console.log(e.target.name);
        switch (e.target.name) {
            
            case 'txtName':
                if(e.target.value=='')
                {
                    setstate({...state.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank'})
                }
                setstate({...state, Name:e.target.value})
                break;
                case 'txtEmail':
                setstate({...state, Email:e.target.value})
                break;
                case 'txtSalary':
                setstate({...state, Salary:e.target.value})
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        
        console.log(state);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Name : <input name="txtName" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <label> {this.state.Error.EName==undefined ? '*':this.state.Error.EName} </label>
            <br></br>            
            Email : <input name="txtEmail" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <br></br>            
            Salary : <input name="txtSalary" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <br></br>
            <button onClick={validationHandler}>Validate Us</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReactForm
```

I have nested Error element for validation in state -

```
Error:{
        EName:'*',
        EEmail:'*',
        ESalary:'*'
    }
```

I am trying to bind it to react element as -

```
Name : <input name="txtName" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <label> {this.state.Error.EName==undefined ? '*':this.state.Error.EName} </label>
```

But Getting An Error -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `this` to access state in functional components. Just do, `state.Error.EName`. `this` is only necessary in class components.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. Understood my mistake.

Comment: @CSharper yw. Happens to the best of us. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using functional component and your state is not binded to the class component so you don't need to access it through `this`.

```
return (
  <div>
      Name : <input name="txtName" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
      <label> {state.Error.EName==undefined ? '*': state.Error.EName} </label>
      <br></br>            
      Email : <input name="txtEmail" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
      <br></br>            
      Salary : <input name="txtSalary" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={validationHandler}>Validate Us</button>
  </div>
)
```